# How to run selected text using keyboard shortcut joined together with a command in background?

Tags: linux, text-to-speech, manjaro, xclip

I am trying to be able to select text anywhere within my manjaro linux system and run it along with a TTS text to speech program. The program is called google_speech and it got a really clear default voice and is really easy to use, however I am finding it hard to implement what I want to do with it...

The program is ran by the following command:

```
  $ google_speech -l en "I am just a robot but one day I plan to rule humans"
```

so I am trying to be able to select text and press a keyboard shortcut and the text will automatically be importing here:

```
  $ google_speech -l en "HERE"
```

and ran as a command in the background hopefully without having to open a terminal window but if so then thats totally fine... I was thinking xclip would be able to do this but I can figure out what command or options I need to be using... my research so farhas gotten me nowhere...

Thanks you so much for your time and skills...